# How can I find attributes in RSelenium

Tags: r, xml, rvest, rselenium

I would like to find all "a href" of a particular webpage, there are examples how to do it in XML, rvest or splashr, I would like to do it with Rselenium and *Not* by finding the elements first and then getElementAttribute(..., "href").

I'm looking for something similiar to read_html, html_nodes, html_attr from rvest, or render_html from splashr which later works with rvest.

EDIT: Ideally something similiar to render_html which lets all scrips finish.

Start of code:

```
library(rselenium)
rd <- rsDriver(verbose = F)
remotedriver <- rd$client
remotedriver$navigate('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Now I get stuck on how to find all URLs that points somewhere. I have tried

```
library(xml)
html_parse <- htmlParse(remote$getPageSource()[1])
```

But dont know which functions can be used to work with the html_parse object.